# Use Media Uploader on Multiple Images on same page

Tags: jquery, uploads

I have multiple image user meta fields on the same page and am using a media uploader jquery script to set the URL as the text fields value when the image is clicked.

Works ok on one image field but how can I use over multiple image fields on the same page... ie with ids of *ols_user_meta_image_1* through to *ols_user_meta_image_5*

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
var custom_uploader;



$('.additional-user-image').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

//If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
if (custom_uploader) {
    custom_uploader.open();
    return;
}

//Extend the wp.media object
custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    title: 'Choose Image',
    button: {
        text: 'Choose Image'
    },
    multiple: false
});

//When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
    attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    $('#ols_user_meta_image_1').val(attachment.url);
});

//Open the uploader dialog
custom_uploader.open();

});
```

So at the moment all fields will inherit the unique id of #ols_user_meta_image_1 value, how can the code be adjusted to allow for a range of image ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I set a new variable of target_input that grabs the previous input field ID, this input is where I want the URL of the selected media stored, this is done in the click function of the button that selects the media.

That variable is used to attach the URL.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


var custom_uploader;
var target_input;


$('.additional-user-image').click(function(e) {
    //grab the ID of the input field prior to the button where we want the url value stored
    target_input = $(this).prev().attr('id');

    e.preventDefault();

    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        //Added target_input variable to grab ID and add URL
        $( '#' + target_input ).val(attachment.url);
    });

    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();

});

});
```